# I need a script to change a link when clicked on it to another content

Tags: php

i am working on student supervision project. i wanted to create a page that contain the available project topics, when clicked on a topic of interest, to assigns the topic to the user with that 'id' and renders the link unavailable e.g a topic that has a link 'available' to change to 'unavailable'.

i will really apreciate if someone in the house can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax for it, that way and helping with jquery you make the changes in real time

Comment: Thanks Carlos Quintero. Pls can you help me with the complete script?

Comment: <body>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="2">

<?php
$sql = "Select * from prject_topic";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['lecturer_name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['topic'];?></td>
    <td><a href="#.php?id=<?php echo $row['project_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['status'];?></a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>

Comment: The script above is what i use to populate the project topic and the name of the supervisor with a link (Available). when click on the link, insert the topic into a table in my DB where project_id=id and render the available link to be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I made some small changes to perform this action with jquery

```
<body>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="2">
    <?php $sql = "Select * from prject_topic"; $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['lecturer_name'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['topic'];?></td>
            <td><span class="actu" id="<?php echo $row['project_id'];?>">
                    <?php echo $row['status'];?>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr> <?php } ?>
    </table>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //We capture the Click in the user item
        $(".actu").on('click', function(){
            //We take the ide of this item
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                //We check the current status of the user
                if($(this).html() == "Deactivate"){
                    var est = "Activate";
                }else{
                    var est = "Deactivate";
                }

            //We made a request of type ajax sending by post the id for its update
            $.post('#.php',
                        {
                            'id':id,
                            'est':est
                        },
                        //We received the response from our php file which may be a code as in the example...
                        function(data){

                            if(data=="200"){
                                //If yes, update the content of the selected item in real time
                                $("#"+id).html('Deactivate');
                            }else{
                                //In case of error, we send the information
                                alert("Unable to disable user");
                            }

                    })
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```

The code is written for your understanding

Comment: In the response function you must place the impression that you select the code in the variable est, I'm missing that there...

Comment: for example: `$("#"+id).html(est);`

Comment: Carlos thanks for the script. i succeeded using mysqli update function.